# Internal WCF Service on a public facing server security

Tags: wcf, web-services, security, iis

I need to host a WCF service that will give its clients access to internal business systems on a public facing web server. Obviously I must secure this so that no one from the outside world even knows the service exists, let alone be able to call methods and access the data it exposes.

The overall idea is that the public facing website hosted on the same machine will call the WCF service and then the WCF service will provide it with the required data...

`Public Facing Web Site <-> WCF Service <-> Business Systems / Databases`

So I need to understand how to secure the service so it can only be accessed via the public facing website.

Ideas I had..

- IIS filtering so that the IIS Site hosting the WCF service will only accept requests from a certain IP address.
- Obscure port that will not be allowed through the public facing firewall.
- Protocol such as NetTCP or NamedPipes

But what about the actual WCF security set up? As both the Public Facing Site and the service are on the same machine is Windows Authentication as option? Questions I have regarding this are...

- Should the service client and the service simply use Windows Authentication?
- Do I need specific user accounts as opposed to Network Service? If the website runs under network service would this then automatically authenticate to the service?

My objective is that someone in the outside world should not know of the services existance or be able to make access to it.

Thanks in advance.

Technical environment is: IIS7, .Net 4 and WCF 4.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a http handler '.ashx' and use that as the endpoint for client requests.

If your using asp.net you can secure it by using simple forms authentication and retrieving username and password from the request headers to authenticate the request.

Then execute any requests to your business webservices which is also secured by your forms authentication.

Cheers